# Mediarecorder: How to support audio recording on Safari, IE 11?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, redux, web-mediarecorder

## Problem Statement

Hi, I want to add support for audio recording using `MediaRecorder` API in my app for **IE 11** and **Safari**, but couldn’t figure anything so far. Are there any **polyfills** available that can help me add support for the same in these browsers?

### Safari:

I can see **Safari** does have `MediaRecorder` API supported under **experimental** features, but even that doesn’t seem to work properly despite giving a proper mime type of `audio/webm`, it always returns a blob of `video/mp4` mime type.

### IE 11:

It's an ancient piece of rubbish, that's all I can say :)

#### Code:

```
const stream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
  audio: true,
  video: false,
})


const mimeType = 'audio/webm'

// check if above mime type is supported in browser and instantiate recorder
if (MediaRecorder.isTypeSupported(mimeType)) {
  this.recorder = new MediaRecorder(this.stream, { mimeType })
} else {
  this.recorder = new MediaRecorder(this.stream)
}

recorder.start()
```

**NOTE:** Please don't ask to ditch these browsers as they are my requirement :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Safari Support:

I was able to add support for `MediaRecorder` API in **Safari** by using **Audio Recorder Polyfill**. You can check this NPM package [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/audio-recorder-polyfill).

#### Steps (React JS):

1. Install the package using `npm i audio-recorder-polyfill`
2. Add this piece of code in **public/index.html**. This will make sure that the polyfill is loaded only for the browsers which do not support `MediaRecorder` API.

```
<script>
  // load this bundle only for browsers without MediaRecorder support
  if (!window.MediaRecorder) {
    document.write(
      decodeURI('%3Cscript defer src="/polyfill.js">%3C/script>')
    )
  }
</script>
```

3. Add this piece of code in **src/index.tsx** or **src/index.js**. This will assign this polyfill to **MediaRecorder** present in **window** object.

```
import AudioRecorder from 'audio-recorder-polyfill'
window.MediaRecorder = AudioRecorder
```

4. If you are using Typescript, you might have to add type declarations in **src/audio-recorder-polyfill.d.ts**

```
declare module 'audio-recorder-polyfill'
```